# iPhone music sync

Tags: raspbian

While I have found a lot of info about shairport and other music streaming tools for the Raspberry Pi, I have not found any which sync music to my iPhone from my Raspberry Pi.

I've tried Banshee and Rhythmbox which I found after quite a search, but they don't seem to be able to recognize my iPhone 6S. (Note, they do only claim iPod syncing! but I tried it anyway).

Also I have tried libimobiledevice using:

```
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils
```

But that didn't have the desired effect either.

What I'm looking for:

A way to sync my music from my NAS, (mounted on my Pi), to my iPhone. (Preferably no third party app but the music app from Apple). Wi-Fi sync would be a plus but I'd be happy not having to boot my laptop for itunes.

I might be asking for the impossible but I do hope it's possible. If it is not possible using the native music app, I am open to third party apps, though the ones I've used always seem to have a flaw in them that spoils the experience for me.

on a side note, during my search I've stumbled across this [Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org/) music server. Seems great but again, not through the native music app. Might check it out when I'm a little further down the road.

Tech info: Raspberry Pi 2, using Raspbian, gui is a plus but not required (i'm no stranger to CLI), IOS 9.3

Comment: *"I might be asking for the impossible but I do hope it's possible."* -> I believe the very explicit intention of Apple is that it **not** be possible.  This doesn't mean that this is something they or other cooperating parties can enforce legally under all circumstances, but it does mean they can go out of their way (including investing millions of R&D dollars) to make sure it is too difficult for anyone to bother implementing a solution, even for those circumstances where no real law could possibly be violated (I would like to stream my own created music, etc).

Comment: ...Hence you are bound to see a succession of solutions that may have worked for some period of time, then they don't.

Comment: Indeed, this is exactly what I'm experiencing. I do know about copytans on windows, but that's the only real itunes workaround i've found so far. And again, this is not for raspberry pi so I won't bother since i can just use itunes at that point :) looks like it's going to have to be third party music apps

Comment: Next time you spend $500 on one of the phones remember: 10%+ of that actively went toward coming up with ways to make sure you *can't* use it the way you want. ;\

Comment: haha, thanks for the advice ;-) This question was in no way a protest/criticism towards apple's policy. I'm still an apple-fan!

Comment: Maybe you could try jailbreak? I'm pretty sure that the point of jailbreak is to remove Apple's efforts on restricting what you can do. You may want to wait for a jailbreak for iOS 9.3 without upgrading to another version

Comment: I've had a jailbroken device in the past. It can do this using, for example, bridge. However I'm not inclined to jailbreak at this point. While it does add a lot of fun features, it also complicates things more than I'd like